# The application gives a stopped error when I build

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

There is no problem in running my game in the unity editor but when I build it on the phone the application gives an error that stopped.
HELP PLS!!

Comment: please show log or something its impossible to help otherwise

Comment: Running game in editor and on real device both are different scenarios. If you are using high textured models and not optimised your game for the small device it may occur. Just create a simple scene and try to run it if it's fine then you need to optimize your game.Some  times other issues may be well so..try it

Comment: please provide more information about your error or any specific section when you are getting it.

Comment: We need to see logs or error when you try to build otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Log mesajlarını nasıl görebilirim yardımcı olabilir misiniz?